# Cannot train a CNN (or other neural network) to fit (or even over-fit) on Keras + Theano

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, theano

For learning purposes, I am trying to implement a CNN from scratch, but the results do not seem to improve from random guessing. I know this is not the best approach on home hardware, and following course.fast.ai I have obtained much better results via transfer learning, but for a deeper understanding I would like to see, at least in theory, how one could do it otherwise.

Testing on CIFAR-10 posed no issues - a small CNN trained from scratch in a matter of minutes with an error of less than 0.5%.

However, when trying to test against the Cats vs. Dogs Kaggle dataset, the results did not bulge from 50% accuracy. The architecture is basically a copy of AlexNet, including the non-state-of-the-art choices (large filters, histogram equalization, Nesterov-SGD optimizer). For more details, I put the code in a notebook on GitHub:

https://github.com/mspinaci/deep-learning-examples/blob/master/dogs_vs_cats_with_AlexNet.ipynb

(I also tried different architectures, more VGG-like and using Adam optimizer, but the result was the same; the reason why I followed the structure above was to match as closely as possible the Caffe procedure described here:
https://github.com/adilmoujahid/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial
and that seems to converge quickly enough, according to the author's description here: http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/06/introduction-deep-learning-python-caffe/).

I was expecting some fitting to happen quickly, possibly flattening out due to the many suboptimal choices made (e.g. small dataset, no data augmentation). Instead, I saw no increment at all, as the notebook shows.

So I thought that maybe I was simply overestimating my GPU and patience, and that the model was too complicated even to overfit my data in a few hours (I ran 70 epochs, each time roughly 360 batches of 64 images). Therefore I tried to overfit as hard as I could, running these other models:

https://github.com/mspinaci/deep-learning-examples/blob/master/Ridiculously%20overfitting%20models...%20or%20maybe%20not.ipynb

The purely linear model started showing some overfit - around 53.5% training accuracy vs 52% validation accuracy (which I guess is thus my best result). That followed my expectations. However, to try and overfit as hard as I could, the second model is a simple 2 layers feedforward neural network, without any regularization, that I trained on just 2000 images with batch size up to 500. I was expecting the NN to overfit wildly, quickly getting to 100% train accuracy (after all it has 77M parameters for 2k pictures!). Instead, nothing happened, and the accuracy flattened to 50% quickly enough.

Any tip about why none of the "multi-layer" models seems able to pick any feature (be it "true" or out of overfitting) would be very much appreciated!

Note on versions etc: the notebooks were run on Python 2.7, Keras 2.0.8, Theano 0.9.0. The OS is Windows 10, and the GPU is a not-so-powerful, but that should be sufficient for basic tasks, GeForce GTX 960M.